# Puppet - install module through other module manifest

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

I'd like to use vcsrepo module in my puppet module manifest. So I need to install puppetlabs/vcsrepo. 
Is it possible to avoid installing it manualy by command
`sudo puppet install puppetlabs-vcsrepo`?
I've tried to use somethink like this in my init.pp file

```
module { 'puppetlabs/vcsrepo':
    ensure   => installed,
}
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Well no, what you tried probably wouldn't work, because there is no `module` resource type in the standard distribution.  You should not try to guess at resource type names or attributes; consult the [type reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html) for your Puppet version instead.

Comment: You can write an `Exec` that ensures a module is installed on the target system, but the usefulness of that is unclear.  Certainly a module installed that way would be unavailable until the next Puppet run.  Moreover, although it might serve a purpose in a `puppet apply` context, it makes no sense at all in a master / agent context, for Puppet modules are used during catalog building.  It is not useful to install them anywhere other than the machine(s) where catalogs are built.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use that module would be to add it to your metadata.json file as explained here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#module-metadata

Once you've done so the module requested, in your case puppetlabs/vcsrepo will be installed.